# reading several variable types from file

Tags: c++

I have a file that looks like this:

```
5,4,A
6,3,A
8,7,B
7,6,B
5,2,A
9,7,B
```

I'm trying to create a class function that reads a line and inserts the contents into x,y,featClass respectively. The variable types are int x,y and char featClass. From that point, I can create an object of the class named sample1, which will contain x,y,and featClass from it's respective line in the file.

To clarify, each line represents a sample. I will create an object of my class for each sample line, and name the objects sample1, sample2, Etc...

I wrote the code to read the file in main to make sure it was working correctly before I insert the code into my class function. However, when I run the program and read the first line into x, y, and featClass, the resulting values for each variable are 1,0,P respectively, which does not match the first line 5,4,A.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  //init variables
  int x,y;
  char featClass;

  //get x,y, and output params from input file
  char filename[50];
  ifstream sampleFile("sampleFile.txt");
  //cin.getline(filename,50);
  sampleFile.open(filename);

  if(!sampleFile.is_open())//check if file is not open
  {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);//terminates program if file is not opened correctly
  };

  while(sampleFile.peek() == ',')
  {
    sampleFile.ignore(1);`
    sampleFile >> x >> y >> featClass;
  };

  cout << x << " " << y << " " << featClass << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I'm wondering why my code outputs 1,0,P into x, y, and featclass.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a ` after    sampleFile.ignore(1);
And what I would do is make a for statement iterating through each character, looking for a match for "1", and if it's found, removing it.

Comment: What I don't understand is why is it returning those values? Neither of the 3 values are found anywhere in the text file I'm reading from.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `cin.peek()`, you should rather use getline() to read the entire line.

```
 while(getline(sampleFile, line))
  {
    //do stuff here
  };
```

Then, parse the line and store the values into x,y and featClass using `stringstream`

So your code (reading file and parsing it) would look similar to this:

```
  char ch;   <-- include this for comma
  while(getline(sampleFile, line))
  {
       //do stuff here
       stringstream sstream(line);
       //this is for your particular problem as your file format is --> int, int, char
       sstream >> x >> ch >> y >> ch >> featClass;
       cout << x << " " << y << " " << featClass << endl;
  };
```

Check out this link to read and learn more about `stringstream`

http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~breech/progteam/stringstream.html